# Showing boundedness of $\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i\}_{n\geq 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a very simple question about infinite series, which is as follows:

Suppose that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence in $[0,1]$. Suppose that the sequence of partial sums $\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded. **Is it true that the sequence $\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded too?**

What I realized, is that the assumption $b_n \geq 0$ cannot be dropped, since one can take $a_n = (-1)^n$ and $b_n = (-1)^n/n$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Note that if you restrict $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ to be a sequence of non-negative real numbers (or, alternatively, non-positive), then the rest of your question will be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not always true. You were close to the solution yourself. For example, use your $a_i = (-1)^i$, plus $b_i = 1$ for $i$ odd and $b_i = 0$ for $i$ even. Then $a_i b_i$ would be $-1$ for $i$ odd and $0$ for $i$ even, so the partial sums $\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\}_{n\geq 1}$ are not bounded and, instead, will go to $-\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: thanks for the counterexample! Can you please tell me what happens if we assume that $\sum_{n=1} a_n < \infty$? By that I mean conditional convergence of the series.

Comment: @Usermath I just realized $\sum_{n=1}a_n b_n$ would not necessarily conditionally converge. For example, from Wikipedia's [Conditional convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence) article, the alternating harmonic series converges to $\ln 2$. If the $b_n$ were to be $0$ for the negative terms and $1$ for the positive ones, then $\sum_{n=1}a_n b_n$ would diverge. In general, if $a_n$ can have an infinite # of both positive & negative terms, then the behavior (e.g., convergence) may be (and often will be) affected by choosing the terms of just one sign.